# MongoDB Exception caching while updating data

Tags: mongodb

Hello every one I'm new to mongodb. While i updating the table i have to get the return values in `result`. But it return `undefined` ,But in the case of `find` and `insert` the value in table it works properly.

```
  bands.update({name:'Hollywood Rose'}, {$set:{year:2000}}, function(err, result) {
console.log("result----"+result) // it returns undefined
        if (!err)     
return context.sendJson(result, 404);
    })

;
```

Comment: on which platform you are using mongodb

Comment: i have the same problem but in java i have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

This code work in my case while i update value in the table in mongodb i did this code in playframe work for java . Hope it also help in you case.

```
    MongoClient mongo=new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    /*mongo.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.JOURNALED);*/
    DB db = mongo.getDB("webportal"); 
    DBCollection coll=db.getCollection("userdb");
    //ObjectId id= new ObjectId(userid); 
    BasicDBObject doc2 = new BasicDBObject();
    doc2.put("_id",userid);
    BasicDBObject updateDocument = new BasicDBObject();
    updateDocument .append("$set", new BasicDBObject("username", username1).append("password", password1).append("email", email1));
    coll.update(doc2, updateDocument);
```